# Npgsql 3.0.5 with writer.Write Geometry type

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have upgrade from Npgsql 2.7.0 to 3.0.5 , COPY (Bulk Data Transfer) is change
I have seen this [doc](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html) and try to using new COPY method.

with Npgsql 2.7.0 using "NpgsqlCopyIn" in my code  case "geometry" was fine.

Now with 3.0.5 : error at writer.Close()

```
{"XX000: Invalid endian flag value encountered."}
```

this is my code ...

```
var query = String.Format("COPY \"{0}\".\"{1}\"  ({2}) FROM STDIN BINARY;",a,b,c)
var writer = conn.BeginBinaryImport(query); 
var o = Common.IO << ...read from zip file... >>
for (int row = 0; row < o.Count; row++) 
{
   writer.StartRow();
   for (int col = 0; col < (o[row].Count - 1); col++)
   {
     switch (columns.ElementAt(col).Value)
       case "varchar":
           writer.Write(o[row][col].ToString().Replace("\0", ""));
           break;
       case "geometry"
           writer.Write<String>((String)o[row][col]);
           break;
       case "int4":
           writer.Write<Int32>(Convert.ToInt32(o[row][col]));
           break;
   }

}
writer.Close();
```

In case "geometry", I have try this following;

```
writer.Write<String>(String.Format("ST_GeomFromText('{0}')", (String)o[row][col]));
```

or

```
writer.Write<String>(String.Format("ST_GeomFromText('{0}')", (String)o[row][col]), NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Line);
```

Not success! Please help

suggestion will be highly appreciated,

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Npgsql's binary import COPY doesn't work in the way that you're trying. Npgsql itself is responsible for encoding values to PostgreSQL's binary formats - you're not supposed to provide binary data as you're doing. For example, to COPY an int you provide a plain, regular CLR int and not a 4-byte array - Npgsql takes care of everything.

Regarding geometry specifically - I'm assuming you're referring to PostGIS. Binary support for PostGIS doesn't exist yet in Npgsql 3.0, so unfortunately it's not possible to do a binary COPY of those types. Npgsql 3.1 contains support for most (but not all) geometry types, but it's still in alpha. A good workaround could be to import your geometry values via text, in which case you're responsible for providing a properly-formatted text representation of your values (see the COPY docs for more details).

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wkt As String = g.ToString '"POINT(7 7)"
Dim udtText As New System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars(wkt)
Dim sqlGeometry1 As Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry = Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.STGeomFromText(udtText, srid)
Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(ms)
Dim WKB() As Byte = sqlGeometry1.STAsBinary().Buffer
bw.Write(WKB)
dbimporter.Write(WKB, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bytea)
```